# Organize <div> or something else in <td>

Tags: html, css-float

I'm quite new in html & css. Anyway, I have a page to design and particularly a table where I have different information in each cell. So I need to put information in each corner and in the center.

I found a solution, but i'm not fully happy with as i can't reduce the size of the cell.

Here is my html :

```
<td>
  <div class ="upperleft"> x </div>
  <div class = "upperRight"> x </div>
  <div class = "center"> x </div>
  <div class ="bottomleft"> x </div>
  <div class = "bottomRight"> x </div>   
</td>
```

and in my css I use float left or rigth for the bottom or upper DIV.

Have you got any other solution for such situation?

Comment: Sounds like you could benefit from a table within your table-cell. That seems to be what you are laying out anyways. You just need to make sure the middle-column has a height of two rows.

Answer (score 1):

To make my comment an answer:

```
<td>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>top-left</td>
      <td>bottom-left</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2">center</td>
    </td>
    <tr>
      <td>top-right</td>
      <td>bottom-right</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</td>
```

Comment: I tensed up at the idea of nested tables, but then I realized that it might actually be the best representation of the data. :)

Comment: Well, if it's tabular data, then a table works! lol. Now, if we're talking about design elements, then divs are _typically_ better.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. As you say john, this is more design elements, as the center information has not the same size as the others. Unfortunately, i did not succeed in "overlapping" div even with z-index. May be i'm wrong somewhere but can't find it.